# Control display output using vector

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, vector, cout

Vector size: 2

Vector data: Carol Mary

```
if(vector.size() >=2)
{
    cout<<vector.size();

    for(int i=1;i<vector.size()-2;i++)
    {
        cout<<" AND ";
    }
}
```

Output display: Carol AND Mary AND

How do i change it to Carol AND Mary?

and when my vector size is 3,

How do i change it to Carol AND Mary AND Peter

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From where Carol, Mary & Peter are coming ? Are they in vector ?

Comment: @P0W they are from the vector

Comment: I'm pretty sure you missed `vector[i] <<`. Try to construct [a short, *complete* running program](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) and copy-and-paste its code into the question.

Comment: Don't call your vector `vector`, that will just lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets assume the vector is named v.

```
if(!v.empty()) {
  cout << v[0];
  for(int i = 1; i<v.size(); ++i) {
    cout << " AND " << v[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Good call, I believe i fixed the answer now. Require it to be non empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use my `infix_ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
         infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " AND "));
```

The `infix_ostream_iterator` code is on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my preferred way:

```
const char *sep = "";
for (size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i, sep=" AND ")
    cout << sep << vec[i];
cout << endl;
```

Or, even shorter:

```
cout << join(vec, " AND ") << endl;
```

That is, using boost::algorithm::join(), works like in Python (`" AND ".join(vec)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::string> vec {"Carol","Marry","Peter"};

int i=1;
std::cout<<vec[0];

for(;i<vec.size();++i)
  std::cout<<" AND "<<vec[i];
```